# Can't download Steam

Tags: 12.04, software-center, steam, chromebook

When I try to download Steam from the software center, I'm asked to put in a password to authorize it.

I put my password in then I get "to change software repository settings, you need to authenticate" so I put my password in again and I get " to update software catalogue, you need to authenticate. Then it says it is installing but it never does.

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install` and/or rebooting the system? This should just work, but something in the cache may have gotten stuck, or there could be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

To install Seam, download the .deb file from the [Steam website](http://store.steampowered.com/about/). 
After you download it, just run the file to install it.

Comment: Yes, Steam is in the Software Center. It is a "for purchase" application, with a price of $0.00, though.

Comment: Can't see any justification for a down vote on this comment. Have up-voted to cancel it out.

Comment: For one, it formerly stated that steam wasn't available in the software center at all, without manually adding a PPA. Now, it still does not answer the question asked. It simply says to go get steam from somewhere else, not how to solve the issue presented in the question.